# statically initialized objects can't be placed in the block try

Tags: c++, exception, global-variables, try-catch

I'm reading the book Inside the C++ Object Model and I got a paragraph as below:

> There are a number of drawbacks to using statically initialized
>   objects. For example, if exception handling is supported, these
>   objects cannot be placed within try blocks. This can be particularly
>   unsatisfactory with statically invoked constructors because any throw
>   will by necessity trigger the default terminate() function within the
>   exception handling library.

If I get it correctly, it means that

```
MyGlobalObject obj;

int main()
{
    try
    {
        // do something with obj here is unsatisfactory
    }
    catch(...){}

    return 0;
}
```

is not good. But I don't know why. Why any throw will be necessity trigger the default terminate() function.

Comment: You never define obj is static, so you can handle the exceptions in the try/catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it means is you can't catch exceptions from statically initialized objects because they are initialized **before** `main()` starts making it *impossible* to surround them with a `try{}` block.

```
MyGlobalObject obj; // this initializes before main() starts

int main()
{
    try
    {
        // too late to protect the static initialized global
        // with this try block during its initialization
        // but any operations you perform on it afterwards
        // inside this try{} block will be fine.
    }
    catch(std::exception const& e)
    {
    }
}
```

One solution to this is to put the static objects in a *function* like this:

```
MyGlobalObject& get_my_global_object()
{
    // This will not initialize until this function
    // is called for the first time.
    static MyGlobalObject obj;
    return obj;
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        // now if the global object throws during its
        // initializatin the exception will be caught.
        MyGlobalObject& obj = get_my_global_object();
    }
    catch(std::exception const& e)
    {
    }
}
```